# JQGrid with JScrollpane: scroller jumps around

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-jscrollpane

I am using a JQGrid which has a Jscrollpane inside it. The Grid has pagination to it.

When I select 10 or 20 records and after that I scroll down the grid, the scroller jumps to the top even if I scroll using the mousewheel plugin. It is always on top, it just won't come down.

If I use normal scroll bars, everything works fine. I have tried `maintainPosition:true` and `false` but even then, the scroller is always on top.

```
gridComplete: function(){
                var table_header = $('#gbox_list').find('.ui-jqgrid-hbox').css("position","relative");
            $('#gbox_list').find('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').bind('jsp-scroll-x', function(event, scrollPositionX, isAtLeft, isAtRight){
          table_header.css('right', scrollPositionX);
         }).jScrollPane({
             showArrows: true, 
            autoReinitialise: true,            
        horizontalDragMaxWidth: 30,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 30,  
        maintainPosition:false
      });
            },
```

[Working model](http://jsfiddle.net/F24XM/)

Keep using the scrollbar and try selecting 5///10///20 records... You will notice the error.

Everytime the content gets changed, I need the scrollbar to be on the top as well as to the left when reinitialized.

Comment: i have simply added ""$(".jspPane").css({'top':''});""....but the MOUSEWHEEL GETS AFFECTED...I DUNNO WHY...HERES THE RE-MODELED WORKING FIDDLE..http://jsfiddle.net/F24XM/2/

NOW...with selection of 5 or 10 or 20 records...the scrollpane works fine...except that the MOUSEWHEEL IS'NT..working properly now...

Comment: ALSO I VE TOOK OUT 'maintainPosition:boolean' out...is there anyother way to solve this prob in an optimised way ?..PLEASE HELP ME OUT...I WILL HAVE SOLVED ALL MY MAJOR PROBS RELATED TO THIS..THANKS...GOOD DAY Y'LL ! CHEERS !

Comment: but adding $(".jspPane").css({'top':''})(which ive figured out using firebug) seems to be NOT AN OPTIMISED solution because the MOUSEWHEEL GETS AFFECTED....ANYONE...???...HELP ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did 3 things to get this working.

1. `jScrollPane` was not initializing from inside jqGrid's `gridComplete` function so I moved it to the end of the script.
2. I then initialized `jScrollPane` against `$('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv')`.
3. I commented out `autoReinitialise: true`.

Put this at the end of your script and comment out the contents of `gridComplete`.

```
$('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').jScrollPane({
  showArrows: true, 
  //autoReinitialise: true,            
  horizontalDragMaxWidth: 30,
  verticalDragMaxHeight: 30,     
  maintainPosition:false
});
```